# Are there proposals for modeling cache in standard C++? Or any plan?

Tags: c++, caching

As I learn more and more about standard C++, I see more and more speakers, authors, and bloggers emphasize the importance of cache-hit for performant programs. Yet I haven't seen any efforts, in the standard or any proposals, to deal with this issue, except the usual suggestion of "use vectors, because the memory is contiguous".

My observation can certainly be biased, and of course, different hardware platforms have different memory hierarchy structures, PC and embedded systems are totally different worlds (my experience is with PC only). Striving to be portable and to avoid making assumptions that would restrict the use case is the core philosophy of C++. But cache use is too important to be a topic left un-dealt-with. And, in my primitive understanding, as multicore become (or is already) the main hardware platform programs run on, cache utility become even more important.

So, does anyone know if there's any plan to address this topic? Or it should not be addressed in the standard at all because it is an implementation-level problem? 
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "address"?

Comment: It isn't at all clear what such a proposal would consist of. The choice between linked lists and arrays for example is made by the programmer prior to compile time, and without resort to specific language features.

Comment: @EJP Jonathan Blow has been talking about language features that are designed around cache optimization. https://youtu.be/ZHqFrNyLlpA It's not for C++ but it shows such features can exist and what some of them might be. For example structures of arrays in a syntactically intrinsic manner or inheriting by a pointer so base class data is contiguous in memory.

Comment: My question is inherently ambiguous to some (maybe quite a high) degree. I guess (yes, "guess" tells you how much I know about the topic) I want to know if people are trying to figure out, on some abstract level, to make better use of the memory hierarchy.

Comment: To draw an (possibly inappropriate) analogy, RAII is an idiom that is supported at the language level. And "make better use of memory hierarchy" is another idiom that's worth supporting as well, in my opinion.